# Style is not working in android webview

Tags: android, html, css, webview

This is my **form** -

```
    <form name="clmbLead" id="clmbLead_{{FROM_ID}}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="lineItem_{{FROM_ID}}">
    <input type="hidden" id="ItemId_{{FROM_ID}}">
    <div class="form_div"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closeBtn" onclick="closeLeadfrm('{{FROM_ID}}')">x</a> <div class="form" id="form_{{FROM_ID}}">
    <p>Submit your details in the form below:</p> 
    <div class="fild"><label for="name" >Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name_{{FROM_ID}}" placeholder="Name" onKeyPress="removeError(this.id)">
    </div> 
    <div class="fild"><label for="mobile" >Mobile No.</label>
    <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile_{{FROM_ID}}" maxlength="10" placeholder="Mobile No."onKeyPress="removeError(this.id)" >
    </div> 
    <div class="fild"><label for="email" >Email ID</label>
    <input style="width:261px" type="text" name="email" id="email_{{FROM_ID}}" placeholder="Email ID" onKeyPress="removeError(this.id)">
    </div> 
    <br clear="all">
    <div style="text-align:center"> 
    <button class="submit_1" onclick="return 

    ReadLeads('{{FROM_ID}}')">Submit</button> 
    </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="thanku-msg" id="thanku-msg_{{FROM_ID}}" style="display: none;">Thanks for sharing your Details!<br>We shall get back to you soon
    </div>
    </div> 
     </form>
```

`form` is loading properly in `webview`. But If I add following **style** above the `form` it doesn't work -

```
<style> 
 .main_div {position: absolute; width: 100%;top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%;z-index: 9; margin-top:10px;overflow:hidden; } 
 .main_div .required { border-color:red !important; } 
 .main_div .form_div {    background-color: #f5f5f5;border: 1px #dddddd solid;font: normal 14px arial; min-height: 250px;max-width: 500px;max-height: 250px;} 
 .main_div .form_div .form {width:92%;float: left;padding:10px 4%;} 
 .main_div .form_div .form .fild {width:50%;float: left;} 
 .formobile .form_div .form .fild {width:100%;} 
 .main_div .form_div .form .fild label {width: 100%;display: block;padding-bottom:3px;} 
 .formobile .form_div .form .fild label {display:none;} 
 .main_div .form_div .form .fild input {width:90%;padding:10px 0;margin-bottom:10px;padding-left:8px;border-radius:1px;border:1px #c1c1c1 solid;}
.formobile .form_div .form .fild input {width:100%;margin-bottom:15px;} 
 .main_div .form_div .form p {padding:0;margin:0;padding-bottom:10px;margin-bottom:10px;border-bottom:1px #dcdcdc solid;} 
 .formobile .form_div .form {padding-top:60px;padding-bottom: 20px;} 
 .formobile .form_div .form p {position: absolute;width:100%;left:0;top:0;padding: 10px 0;background-color:#EAEAEA;} 
 .formobile .form_div .form p::before {margin-left:10px;content: ""} 
 .main_div .form_div .form button.submit_1{padding:10px 30px;background-color:#e52b02;border:none;border-radius:5px;color: #FFFFFF;font:normal 15px arial;cursor: pointer;} .main_div .form_div .closeBtn {text-decoration: none;font: bold 20px arial;color: #000;right: 0;padding: 5px 10px;} .formobile .form_div .closeBtn {background-color:#EAEAEA;background-color: #DDDDDD;padding: 7px 15px;border-left:1px #D3D3D3 solid;} 
 .main_div .form_div .thanku-msg {position: absolute;margin:auto;left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;width: 250px;height: 50px;text-align: center;} 
 .callLdForm {width: 81px; font: normal 11px arial; text-decoration: none; color: #353535;  text-align: center; display: block;  padding: 2px 0;background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2); border: 1px #A9A6A6 solid;border-radius: 3px;}
</style>
<div class="main_div" id="Lead_Frm_{{FROM_ID}}">
```

I tried by putting this style in **CSS** file and adding that CSS file. But that also didn't work.
Please suggest how to make this style work.

WebView code ( I tried with content and file both way)-

```
browser = new WebView(this);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
setContentView(browser,lp);
browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
browser.addJavascriptInterface(new abcInterface(this), "abc");

//put as content
browser.loadData(content, "text/html", "UTF-8");

//or put as html file
browser.loadUrl("file:///storage/emulated/0/dummy6.html");
```

Comment: your android webview code?

Comment: Added webview code. please check now.

Comment: have you try on browser? this html file completlly work on browser?

Comment: yes. This file perfectly works on browser (both android and windows PC).

Comment: try to using assets folder in html file and called in assest

Comment: I'm not sure, but aren't you supposed to close the input tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**css/style** is taking too much time to load.

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
setContentView(browser,lp);
```

And their is no width and height parameter in `style` or `body`, so this code set the webview width and height to 0 and loaded data become invisible.

Set fixed width and height layoutparam and it becomes visible.